# How can I get my NXT to turn on - all it does is softly click?

Tags: nxt, repair

Recently when I plugged my NXT brick into my PC I clicked on the wrong option and now all it does is clicks when I turn it on? How do I get it back to a usable state?

Comment: I have the same problem. My NXT still doesn't work. Does anyone have any other ideas how to fix it? My NXT is always in the "Samba mode" (Click...click...click...click...) I tried all I know. I don't see any device that could be the NXT in the device manager. I'm using WIN10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using NXT-G, the software that comes with the NXT set, then here is what you do:

1. Get into NXT-G, start a new program.
2. Select the **tools** option, and from the drop-down menu, select **"Update NXT Firmware..."**
3. Plug your **USB** cable (one comes with the set) into your NXT. Don't try using bluetooth, as it won't work.
4. Click the **download** button on the interface which popped up at the end of step 2.
5. Don't unplug your NXT, wait until it **reboots** with its **firmware** loaded.

Congratulations! You have just brought your NXT out of SAMBA mode!

Answer (score 1):

This means your NXT is spoiled and needs reseting. This is usally caused by unplugging before the program downloaded.

To reset 

1) Completely disconnect your NXT from the computer (no USB connection). 
2) Remove all external BlueTooth dongles from your computer, and turn BlueTooth off on the computer (just to be sure).
3) Reboot the computer (this is to make sure no other application is trying to compete for the USB port).
4) Restart the Mindstorms application (and, if possible, don’t start any other applications).
5) Remove one battery from the NXT for a couple of seconds, then reinsert it.
5) Push the NXT reset button firmly for five seconds (make sure you actually press it, and press it for the whole five seconds).
6) Now (with the NXT clicking and the environment up and running), connect the NXT to the computer via the USB cable. Preferably use a “primary” USB port, one on the computer itself and not on a keyboard or monitor.
7) On a PC, you can go to the device manager and check to see if the NXT shows up in “Firmware Update Mode” (if not, you may need to uninstall and reinstall the software and drivers)
8) Update the firmware to 1.03 using the “update firmware” under the tools menu.
9) If this does not work, try *briefly* (one second) pushing the reset button again.

If the above sequence does not work, try repeating steps 1-9 but using a different USB port on the computer.